# Ionic - Dynamic tab creation from JSON response

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I am very new to Ionic and Angular. Basically, I need to create tabs dynamically based on JSON response from my own server.

My JSON response

```
{
"category_id": 1,
"parent_id": 0,
"name": "Root Catalog",
"position": 0,
"level": 0,
"children": [
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "name": "Default Category",
        "is_active": 1,
        "position": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "category_id": 5,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "Masala Mix",
                "is_active": 1,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 2,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "category_id": 3,
                "parent_id": 2,
                 "name": "Pure spices",
                "is_active": 1,
                "position": 2,
                "level": 2,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "category_id": 6,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "Pickles",
                "is_active": 1,
                "position": 3,
                "level": 2,
                "children": []
            },
       ]}]}
```

My output should be with the creation of 3 tabs with a name as "Masala Mix", "Pure Spices" and "Pickles". But what I get now is only one tab creation with the name "Default category"

```
<ion-tabs >
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab *ngFor="let rew of people" [root]="rew.root" [tabTitle]="rew.name">
 </ion-tab>
<ion-tab *ngFor="let cat of rew?.children" [tabTitle]="cat.name"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

TypeScript File

```
loadPeople() {

this.peopleSearch.load()
    .then(data1 => { 

      this.people = data1.children;
                console.log("Tabs : "+this.people);
    }
);
}
```

Browser console output : Tabs : [object Object]

HTTP provider

```
  export class PeopleSearch {
  data1: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Hello PeopleSearch Provider');
  }

 load() {
if (this.data1) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.data1);
}

// Dont have the data yet
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.http.get('http://happyos.in/cat.php')

    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data1 = data;
      resolve(this.data1);
    });
});
}  
}
```

Output [image]

[image]

Comment: to get detailed console output use console.log("Tabs : " ,this.people); instead of +

Comment: try using this.people = data1.children.children

Comment: already tried that. Not working. error is "undefined:children"

Comment: Use `this.people = data1.children[0].children`

Comment: @aminarghavani you are correct but if there are more children in `data1.children` it' won't work right. Actually, the data is very complex. He should simplify it before using it in the html template

Comment: @Mr_Perfect Yep your right but i just answer the question:)

Comment: @aminarghavani Worked fine. I have no intention of adding more children in data1.children.

Comment: @Sumi In that case, store data directly in the object. Why are making it as object in an array? Store the data as simple as you can.

Comment: if you comment line `<ion-tab *ngFor="let cat of rew?.children" [tabTitle]="cat.name"></ion-tab>` is it working? I doubt scope of `rew` variable. its defined in first `*ngFor` and used outside in second `*ngFor`.

Comment: Does this technique result in "Dynamic Tabs"?